# BankAccount.credit & BankAccount.debit -- deprecated or not?

Tags: balanced-payments

The BalancedPayments 1.1 documentation talks about using `Customers` and `Orders` as core transaction objects, but for our application, it's not particularly necessary or useful (our model is *not* a marketplace of buyers and sellers). We'd just like to directly credit/debit to/from `BankAccounts`.

It currently works, but the `credit` and `debit` apis have been removed from the online docs. Is my project at risk unless I implement Customer and Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods, themselves, are not deprecated, but marketplaces are now required to use orders. That means the `order` parameter needs to be supplied in those requests. Since Orders are required and Orders are created on "merchant" `Customer` instances, the use of `Customer` is also required. `Orders` and `Customers` are very useful, https://www.balancedpayments.com/account-reconciliation.

Feel free to drop by #balanced on Freenode IRC or email support@balancedpayments.com with additional questions.